# Using Net.TCP WCF in IIS

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to setup a NetTCP WCF service.

This is my server code:

**iSync.cs**:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISync
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void UploadMotionDynamic(byte[] jpegStream, string alias, Int16 camIndex, byte[] motionLog, double mul, byte isLive, byte doIsave);
}
```

**Sync.cs**:

```
public class Sync : ISync
{ 
    public void UploadMotionDynamic(byte[] jpegData, string alias, Int16 camIndex, byte[] motionLog,double mul,byte isLive, byte doIsave)
    {
       //do stuff
    }
}
```

**web.config**:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="NetTCPBehaviour">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="65536" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="Sync" behaviorConfiguration="NetTCPBehaviour">
        <endpoint  address="net.tcp://localhost:8888/Sync" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="ISync" name="wsSyncerMotion" bindingConfiguration="NetTCPBindingEndPoint"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTCPBindingEndPoint" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Now it cannot be the port being blocked because I even tested it by turning off the firewall.

- I have made sure 'Net Tcp Listener Adaptor' is running in my
  services.
- I have added net.tcp in my IIS\Advanced Settings| Enabled
  Protocols.
- I have added the Non-HTTP activation setting in .NET
  Features.
- I have followed the links kindly supplied by people here.

The error I get (now) is:

[image: Error image]

(I cannot seem to enlarge this image with viewing in a different tab)

Comment: The error clearly states that the server is unavailable. it says that the metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved. This has nothing to do with ports. Did you also check the event viewer to see what the server reports there? any specific errors there in the event viewer?

Comment: You try to access the service using HTTP which have not been defined in your config (only net.tcp), and to use net.tcp in IIS you have to activate it.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas thanks. Yes, should have looked there. Will look now. Also, i need to check this duplicate answer 1st to see if there are differences in my scenario. thanks

Comment: @jgauffin hi, thanks for your comment. How do I activate it?

Comment: Look at the question that I linked to.

Comment: @jgauffin going through it now - thanks very much!

Comment: @jgauffin I have been through it all and I now get a different error...

Comment: That's a new question instead of an edit

Comment: Hi, yes you are right. I did post as a new question. Sorry for the mess!

Comment: No need for a new question. My bad.